# mss sct.grab won't let me select which monitor to use

Tags: python, python-mss

I have two monitors connected to my computer with both active at the same time.  The monitors are not mirrored - each displays different content.

I need to be able to select in code which of these two monitors I want to use with sct.grab.

I have seen and tested this code:  sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
It works - I can change the "1" to "2" and it will indeed screenshot the other monitor - all of it.  However, I can't figure out how to pass into sct.grab both the parameters for the monitor I wish to use, AND the region of screen I wish to grab for just a partial screenshot.  It seems I can either get a partial screenshot, but not choose the monitor, or I can choose the monitor, but only get the full screen.  I need to choose the monitor, and also choose the region.  I'm looking for help with the appropriate syntax.

I have this code:

```
sct_img = sct.grab({'top': 160, 'left': 160, 'width': 160, 'height': 135})
```

but what I want is somewhere to tell sct.grab which of my two monitors to get this from:  For example, something like a parameter in the dictionary specifying which monitor to use would be nice:

```
sct_img = sct.grab({'mon': 2, 'top': 160, 'left': 160, 'width': 160, 'height': 135})
```

Any help would be apprecitated.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no automatic way of doing that in MSS. Your best shot is to calculate coordinates using values stored in `sct.monitors`.

Something like:

```
mon2 = sct.monitors[2]
box = {
    'top': mon2['top'] + 160,
    'left': mon2['left'] + 160,
    'width': 160,
    'height': 135,
}
sct.grab(box)
```

Comment: Little reminder: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if the answer is good for you :)